# When are 'all-' and 'manch-' singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, declension

I've just started learning German and one of the books I was reading explains that you can use various words like articles by using the endings of the article cases. My book just says:

```
this/these     dies- (close to speaker)
that/those     jen- (away from speaker)*
all            all- (singular or plural)
each, every    jed- (always singular)
which          welch-
some           manch- (almost always plural)
such           solch-

*Jener used relatively rarely in German, and instead of it one can use dieser (this/that, these/those)
```

Some of the restrictions of plurality make sense to me: *jed-* is always going to be singular because it is referring to the individuals *e.g. jeder Baum* means  "every tree", but some of the others confuse me, namely **all-** and **manch-**.

I would have expected **all-** and **manch-** to always be plural because they are used to talk about many of something *e.g. alle Bäume* means "all trees". When are the singulars used?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Despite the text book rules - do you have some examples where you think the plural and singular could fit (from the "not sure ones")? It is easier to show something on examples. And if it is an example you have to deal with, you might benefit more from the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in German the indefinite pronouns *all* and *manch* can be used in singular. The following examples show this.

[**all**](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/all)

> - Ich wünsche dir *alles* Gute.
>
>   <sup>(I wish you *all* the best.)</sup>
> - Er besitzt *alle* Macht.
>
>   <sup>(He has *all* the power.)</sup>

[**manch**](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/manch)

> - Ich träume *manches* Mal davon.
>
>   <sup>(I dream of it *sometimes*.)</sup>
> - So *manch* einer versteht micht nicht.
>
>   <sup>(*Some* people don't understand me.)</sup>

At least the English *all* is also used with singular here. For *some*, I could not find a corresponding example.

---

**Addition:** In the comments, a user insisted on an example with *all* undeclined. Even though this is not part of the original question, I am providing here a passage from [DUDEN 9](https://books.google.de/books?id=1-HBDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) (8<sup>th</sup> ed., p. 43), partly translated with the help of [DeepL](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator):

> **all-:**
>
> …
> **6. all die Mühe / alle die Mühe – all meine Freunde / alle meine Freunde:** In front of a noun with an article word *all* can be both declined and undeclined. […] In the singular, with masculine and neutral nouns, the undeclined form is common in all cases today: *All der Fleiß war vergebens. All mein Zureden half nichts. Es bedurfte all meines Mutes.* The undeclined form, on the other hand, is no longer needed: *Wozu alles dieses Geschwätz* (Lessing). With feminine nouns, in the nominative and accusative singular both possibilities are equally important (*all / alle meine Arbeit*), while in the genitive and dative the undeclared forms predominate (*all dieser Arbeit war er überdrüssig; ich in all meiner Unschuld und Unwissenheit*).

Comment: Im talking about the use of _all_, e.g. _"All die Macht die er besaß, konnte ihn nicht retten."_

Comment: I think I understand when **all-** is used singularly now. It's for stuff that isn't really countable on it own (I'm guessing that the context of 'power' in your example means influence and if you said "all powers", it would mean having every ability).

Comment: Presumably if I am talking about something like sand, time, water, light, etc. which cannot be divided into separate counting units, I would use the singular. I'm still not 100% sure when you would use something like **alle Macht** vs **all die Macht** though. Would the meaning change?

Comment: Also, I don't really mind if you can't find a corresponding example similar to **manch** if I can know how to use it properly. Is there some kind of condition (similar to the uncountable singular with **all**) that I can use as an indicator of what is appropriate?

Comment: Wait. Is **manch** also used singularly with 'uncountable' things? So, for example, I could say something like *manches Wasser*?  It's singular since a person can't really 'count' water, but it is still 'some'.

Comment: @Nicholas, countability does not play a role. All I say, also with the examples, is that it can be used singularly. *Wasser* is singular, so you can say *manches Wasser*. That in addition *Wasser* is uncountable, is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

### all-

- die **allgemeine** Schulpflicht
  **general** compulsory schooling
- das **alljährliche** Weihnachtsfest
  the **annual** Christmas festival
- der **alleinige** Herrscher
  the **sole** ruler
- der **allseits** bekannte Star
  the **well-known** star
- der **allmächtige** und **allwissende** Gott
  the **almighty** and **omniscient** God

---

### manch

- **Manch einer,** der vor der Versuchung flieht, hofft doch heimlich, dass sie ihn einholt.
- **Someone** who flees temptation secretly hopes that it will catch up with him.

Comment: The question is about inflected forms such as *alle, allen, alles*, not about compounds such as *allgemein*.

Comment: Would be nice to have an example that explains a sentence like _"All die Dinge die Du getan hast ..."_ and how the inflection works there (especially since _Dinge_ is Plural there).